# Can not upload file to the text field(there is hidden file field)

Tags: cypress

I have trouble with file upload. Introducing everything step-by-step.

I have one file upload in the form. But the field's type is text. But in the back, there is a hidden field, that its type is a file upload.

**Visible field (text field):**

```
<div _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="form-group upload-doc ng-star-inserted" id="form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3">                         <label _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="ng-star-inserted">Please provide bank account statement</label><!---->                         <input _ngcontent-ete-c120="" type="text" readonly="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><i _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="fal fa-upload"></i>                         <!---->                          <!---->                       </div> –
```

**Hidden field**

```
<input _ngcontent-juf-c120="" type="file" ng2fileselect="" class="uploader" accept="application/pdf,application/acrobat,application/nappdf,application/x-pdf,image/pdf,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png">
```

I make a hidden field and can add files with invoke-command. But the file's name doesn't written in the text field that I see. That is why can not pass the form. You can see the hidden field at the top where I added the file. Also, the text field that I am uploading file from UI. The file's name I must in this field.

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWOqr.png)

Comment: Why aren't you triggering the required event as suggested in the duplicate of this question a week ago?

Comment: I did it. But it didn't work. Do you have any examples? Can you help pls?

Comment: What event handlers are on the hidden element?

Comment: File upload it is

Answer (score 0):

Do you use libraries like "cypress-file-upload" ? Its really good and i haven't had issues with it so far.

Comment: Yes, I use it..